# Control panel and site not listed in zmi, where is it?

Tags: plone

I'd like to pack my zodb.
I've logged into the zmi from mydomain.com/manage.
I used the username 'admin' and the password I specified in the buildout, and it succeeded. 
However control_panel is not listed when I click on '/' (nor is the site name). 
What am I missing here?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't really looking at the Zope2 application root. Rather, you are looking at the virtual host root (that is most likely proxied by Apache or NGINX some other web server). Try accessing the site on whatever port Zope2 is running on, e.g. 8080.

Also in newer Plones, there is a Maintenance control panel in Site Setup where you can pack (this requires that you have the Manager role at the Zope2 application root).

Comment: Alternatively, you can try accessing to http://www.atf.com.au/aq_parent/manage to get the "manage" ZMI page of the parent object (Zope root) of your Plone site.

Comment: I had that in my answer, but edited it out for security reasons, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

... and you can pack your Data.fs from site setup: (of course as admin)

http://yourplonesite/@@maintenance-controlpanel

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to access http://yourplonesite/Control_Panel/manage_main

This wokrs only if your user is defined on the zope root acl_users.